# How can I get this result in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this data structure:

```
        "_id" : "121212",
        "terms" : [
                {
                        "term" : "hi",
                        "tf" : 2
                },
                {
                        "term" : "you",
                        "tf" : 1
                }
         ]
```

}

and making this query:

```
db.foo.aggregate( [
                {
                        $match : { _id : "121212" }
                },
                {
                        $project:{ terms:1 }
                },
                {
                        $unwind: "$terms"
                }
            ]).pretty();
```

I have come to get this result in my db:

```
{
        "_id" : "121212",
        "terms" : {
                "term" : "hi",
                "tf" : 2
        }
}
{
        "_id" : "121212",
        "terms" : {
                "term" : "you",
                "tf" : 1
        }
}
```

but is there any way to get a result like this?:

```
{
        "_id" : "121212",
        "term" : "hi",
        "tf" : 2
}
{
        "_id" : "121212",
        "term" : "you",
        "tf" : 1
}
```

I have tried to build the query with `$ replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$ terms"}`, but after I can't select the _id field anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage at the end of the pipeline

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { "_id": "121212" } },
  { "$unwind": "$terms" },
  { "$project": { "term": "$terms.term", "tf": "$terms.tf" }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "121212",
    "term": "hi",
    "tf": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "121212",
    "term": "you",
    "tf": 1
  }
]
```

Check it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eXNxHbm5QW3)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use the `$map` and `$mergeObjects` to do this beautifully.

```
[
   { "$match":{"_id":"121212"}},
   {
      "$addFields":{
         "terms":{
            "$map":{
               "input":"$terms",
               "in":{
                  "$mergeObjects":[
                     "$$this",
                     {
                        "_id":"$_id"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

If you really need to deconstruct the "terms" array, then add the `$unwind: "$terms"` to the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) inside `$replaceRoot`:

```
db.foo.aggregate( [
    {
        $match : { _id : "121212" }
    },
    {
        $project:{ terms:1 }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$terms"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [ { _id: "$_id" }, "$terms" ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the range of options:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { "_id": "121212" } }, // filter by "_id"
  { "$addFields": { "terms._id": "$_id" } }, // copy "_id" field into terms
  { "$unwind": "$terms" }, // flatten the "terms" array
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$terms" } } // move the contents of the "terms" field up to the root level
])
```